# Pacific Time in C# regardless of daylight saving time

Tags: c#, .net

I need to ALWAYS stamp my DB with Pacific Time, regardless if it's August or February.
Pacific Time is, the actual US west coast time at anytime of the year:

- During Daylight saving times PT = PDT (Pacific Daylight time) = UTC - 7
- During Non Daylight saving times PT = PST (Pacific Standard Time 0 = UTC - 8

I am using C# and do the following:

```
TimeZoneInfo pacificZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
CreatedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, pacificZone);
```

Would that automatically take into account Daylight saving times, or do I need to account for this by doing this:

```
TimeZoneInfo pacificZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
CreatedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, pacificZone);
if (!TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(CreatedDate))
{
       CreatedDate = CreatedDate.AddHours(-1);
}
```

Comment: You are shooting yourself in the foot by not storing UTC in your DB, and converting to PST accordingly when you need to display it.  UTC is the standard, and is not affected by daylight saving time.  For your use case, you can always subtract 8 hours from UTC to get the value you want.

Comment: @raterus that is not correct, subtracting 8 from UTC will be incorrect during Day light savings time period.

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc WILL use daylight saving time, if the timezone you pass in uses it.  So your first chunk of code is what you should use if you need to display the time, just pull the UTC date from the DB and you're done.

Comment: @Pacman OP wants to keep it non daylight savings. and it appears that UTC-8 is what they want.

Comment: Your requirement is misguided. Its *not* that you want to *store* it in pacific time, it's that someone always wants to *view* the time stamp in pacific time. Do what @raterus stated, always store any `DateTime` value as the UTC value. Convert that value to the appropriate time zone *in the presentation layer* when you want to view it.

Comment: Folks, regardless if I keep it in the DB as UTC, my question is during conversion, how do I guarantee to have the CORRECT time during conversion in case of daylight saving time and non daylight saving times, If my first or 2nd code snippet the correct one

Comment: First code block is the correct one.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read [Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (which is a bit dated, but still some good stuff) and [Choosing between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is my first or 2nd code snippet the correct one?

The first block is the correct one.

---

#### Test code

```
var utcDateDuringDaylightSavingsTime = new DateTime(2018, 7, 1, 15, 30, 30, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeZoneInfo pacificZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var localDateDuringDaylightSavingsTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateDuringDaylightSavingsTime, pacificZone);
var localDateNotDuringDaylightSavingsTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateDuringDaylightSavingsTime.AddMonths(5), pacificZone);

Console.WriteLine(utcDateDuringDaylightSavingsTime.ToString("o") + "\t\tUTC");
Console.WriteLine(localDateDuringDaylightSavingsTime.ToString("o") + "\t\t Local during daylight saving");
Console.WriteLine(localDateNotDuringDaylightSavingsTime.ToString("o") + "\t\t Local not during daylight saving");
```

Output

```
2018-07-01T15:30:30.0000000Z        UTC
2018-07-01T08:30:30.0000000         Local during daylight saving
2018-12-01T07:30:30.0000000         Local not during daylight saving
```